# 2 update in mysql probleme

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, cron

I am searching to in one hand : update all table to a value (in a specific column)
on the other hand : update random row with a new value (in the same specific column).

Exemple :

```
  UPDATE parkplacesalgo SET isvisible=0;
  UPDATE parkplacesalgo SET isvisible=1 WHERE RAND() <= 0.3
```

When I test these request in mysql phpmyadmin: All working.
But in php, it seems doesnt work.

Here is my php code :

```
  $sql1 = "UPDATE parkplacesalgo SET isvisible=0; UPDATE parkplacesalgo SET isvisible=1 WHERE RAND() <= 0.3";
  $objQuery1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1) or die(mysql_error());
```

Moreover, this script will be run every 2 minutes by crons.

If you have an idea. Im little confused.
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you go over the manuals again and stick to the syntax and don't mix mysql apis.

Comment: ok but for my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use case when

```
  UPDATE parkplacesalgo 
  SET isvisible = case when RAND() <= 0.3 then 1 else 0;
```